# Weird typescript errors when using localStorage

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, ionic-framework

I am working on a project for a senior design project and have been getting some odd typeScript errors. I am using typescript 2.3.4.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth'
import { LoginPage } from '../login/login'
import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseObjectObservable} from "angularfire2/database-deprecated";
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import { AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';
/**
 * Generated class for the Profile page.
 *
 * See http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info
 * on Ionic pages and navigation.
 */

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-profile',
  templateUrl: 'profile.html',
})
export class ProfilePage {
  userID: string;
  userProfile: FirebaseObjectObservable<any>;
  profiles: FirebaseObjectObservable<any>;
  public profile = {};
  public items: Array<any> = [];
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,        public af: AngularFireDatabase) {
      this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(user => {
      if(user) this.userID = user.uid;
      this.userProfile = af.object(`userProfile/${user.uid}`);
      this.profiles = af.object(`profiles/${user.uid}/`);
    });
  }

    ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad Profile');
    var tmp1='', tmp2='', tmp3='', tmp4='', tmp5 = '';
    const personRef: firebase.database.Reference =    firebase.database().ref(`profiles/${this.userID}`);
    const personRefCheck: firebase.database.Reference = firebase.database().ref(`profiles/${this.userID}`);
    console.log("personRefCheck: "+personRefCheck);
    personRefCheck.on('value', checkSnapshot => {
      if(!checkSnapshot.val()) {
        console.log("!checkSnapshot");
        //Sets the local variables on load if the profile is null.
        localStorage.setItem('Pname', tmp1);
        localStorage.setItem('Page', tmp2);
        localStorage.setItem('Pabout', tmp3);
        localStorage.setItem('Plocation', tmp4);
        localStorage.setItem('Prating', tmp5);
        }

      else {
        personRef.on('value', personSnapshot => {
          console.log("personalSnapshot");
          this.profiles = personSnapshot.val();
          console.log(this.profiles.name);
          //Sets the variables to the values from database when the page loads
          localStorage.setItem('Pname', this.profiles.name);
          localStorage.setItem('Page', this.profiles.age);
          localStorage.setItem('Pabout', this.profiles.about);
          localStorage.setItem('Plocation', this.profiles.location);
          localStorage.setItem('Prating', this.profiles.rating);
         });
      }
    });
  }

  submitProfileChanges(name, age, about, location, rating) {
     //theoretically should have a .then() promise
     //push a newTask to the 'tasks' database and set the owner and name
     var var1, var2, var3, var4, var5;
     //Variables set to local localStorage
     var1 = localStorage.getItem('Pname');
     var2 = localStorage.getItem('Page');
     var3 = localStorage.getItem('Pabout');
     var4 = localStorage.getItem('Plocation');
     var5 = localStorage.getItem('Prating');

     //If input is is null, sets the input equal to the database, then passes that back to the database
     if(name == undefined){
       name = var1;
     }
     if(age == undefined){
       age = var2;
     }
     if (about == undefined){
       about = var3;
     }
     if (location == undefined){
       location = var4;
     }
     if (rating == undefined){
       rating = var5;
     }
     //Pushes the profile update to the database
     var profUpdate = this.profiles.update({
       name,
       age,
       about,
       location,
       rating
    });
    alert("Profile Updated!");
  }

  logoutUser() {
     this.navCtrl.setRoot(LoginPage);
  }
}
```

This is the section of code that is causing issues. Here are the errors that I get when serving this uncommented.
***Property 'name' does not exist on type 'FirebaseObjectObservable'*** I get this error for age, about, location, and rating.

```
localStorage.setItem('Pname', this.profiles.name);
localStorage.setItem('Page', this.profiles.age);
localStorage.setItem('Pabout', this.profiles.about);
localStorage.setItem('Plocation', this.profiles.location);
localStorage.setItem('Prating', this.profiles.rating);
```

If I comment the above snippet of code out, the program compiles using ionic serve in the terminal line.
Heres the kicker, after serving, I can un comment the code that was commented out, the program will rebuild on its own and will work flawlessly.

Running ionic info spits out the following:

```
cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.0
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.19.0

global packages:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0 

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.8
    Cordova Platforms  : ios 4.5.4
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2

System:

    Node  : v9.9.0
    npm   : 4.6.1 
    OS    : macOS High Sierra
    Xcode : Xcode 9.2 Build version 9C40b 

Environment Variables:

    ANDROID_HOME : not set

Misc:

    backend : pro
```

Answer (score 2):

The error message is telling all you ought to know. You're one step to early.

personSnapshot is a FirebaseObjectObservable that contains the object you want to access. But to get this object you have to subscribe to the FirebaseObjectObservable first!

Try it this way:

```
else {
  personRef.on('value', personSnapshot => {
    console.log("personalSnapshot");

     personSnapshot.subscribe(dbObject => {

        console.log(dbObject.name);
        //Sets the variables to the values from database when the page loads
        localStorage.setItem('Pname', dbObject.name);
        localStorage.setItem('Page', dbObject.age);
        localStorage.setItem('Pabout', dbObject.about);
        localStorage.setItem('Plocation', dbObject.location);
        localStorage.setItem('Prating', dbObject.rating);

     });

  });
}
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested and it returned a runtime error say that undefined is not an object and it also says that property subscribe does not exist on type DataSnapschot. I also dont understand how running ionic serve with that code commented out, and then uncommenting it after it is compiled makes the code work. Maybe it's not clicking for me. Sorry if its a simple concept that I am missing

Comment: Can you please figure out what the output of console.log(personSnapshot) is, if you place it inside personRef.on('value', personSnapshot => {}) ? Maybe personSnapshot is 'undefined'.

Comment: personSnapshot [object Object] is what was logged for personSnapshot.

Comment: Sorry for not having asked this in addition, but what is the output of console.log(dbObject.name); inside personSnapshot.subscribe(dbObject => {});?

Comment: Never makes it that far. Says that personSnapshot.subscribe() does not exist on on type DataSnapshot.

Comment: Sorry to hear that, but then I have no further idea as I don't use Ionic.